# How to launch JavaFX application on command prompt?

Tags: java, deployment, ant, javafx-2

I have created a self-contained application using `JavaFX` deployment task i.e. `<fx:deploy>`. I run this application from command prompt and passes arguments. It supposed to run on command prompt but UI gets open. When I run the executable jar using

```
  java -jar app.jar -action:backup
```

it run on command prompt.

```
<target name="exe" depends="SignedJar">
        <fx:deploy width="800" height="600" nativeBundles="all" outdir="${dist}/winx86" outfile="${app.name}" verbose="true">
                <fx:info title="${app.title}"/>
                <fx:application name="${app.title}" mainClass="${main.class} toolkit=swing"/>
                        <fx:resources>
                            <fx:fileset file="${app.name}.jar"/>
                            <fx:fileset dir="${WorkingFolder}/temp"/>
                </fx:resources>
                <fx:platform>
                        <fx:jvmarg value="-Xms500m"/>
                    <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx1g"/>
                    <fx:jvmarg value="-XX:NewRatio=2"/>
                        <fx:jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=250m"/>
                </fx:platform>

        </fx:deploy>
    </target>
```

**What additionally I need to specify in `<fx:deploy>` so it passes the command line arguments to the application jar?**

Comment: Read the documentation [<fx:param>](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference002.htm#CIACICCF).

Comment: @tarrsalah Thanks. I guess <fx:argument> will work.